firefox devtools javascript script not seen in astyle format
enter image description here
first time learning web hacking, using firefox browser. used f12 to see the devtools <script>, but the scripts are written without the astyle format, just in straight lines like writing in the word document
tried the same thing in chrome browser, the script was seen in the exact format like writing in vscode.
wish firefox devtools look as the same, but how?
